# Conan fails to upload to Artifactory instance over HTTPS

Tags: c++, http, https, artifactory, conan

Currently I have Artifactory set up through a system.yaml file

```yaml
configVersion: 1
shared:
    security:
        exposeApplicationHeaders: true
    node:
        id: "*.example.com"
        ip: artifacts.example.com
    metrics:
        enabled: true
artifactory:
    #port: 8081
    tomcat:
        httpsConnector:
            enabled: true
            port: 8443
            certificateFile: "$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/trusted/server2.crt"
            certificateKeyFile: "$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/trusted/server.key"
frontend:
   featureToggler:
        commonProjects: true
```

And I'm able to access the webview on port 8082 through https just fine

I created a repo for conan artifacts and generated an api key. Then using the "set me up" prompt I ran the following commands on my dev machine
`conan remote add myremote https://artifacts.example.com:8081/artifactory/api/conan/myremote`
`conan user -p <apikey> -r myremote will`

I then get the following error from Conan

```
ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='artifacts.example.com', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /artifactory/api/conan/myremote/v1/ping (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)')))

Unable to connect to myremote=https://artifacts.example.com:8081/artifactory/api/conan/myremote
1. Make sure the remote is reachable or,
2. Disable it by using conan remote disable,
Then try again.
```

I tried to repeat the same steps but using http instead of http and all worked fine. What am I doing wrong that won't let https access work?

Comment: This seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570650/how-to-avoid-a-conan-ssl-user-authentication-error-with-jenkins-artifactory-plug. There are two ways to overcome this. First is to set verifyHttps=false, or replacing Conan remote add with client run.

Comment: @Tom.A Because of company policy using plain http for this isn't an option sadly